# How to translate Xcode 3 properties to Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, video, translate

I am currently watching the video tutorials series by TheNewBoston concerning iPhone development. Unfortunately, he uses Xcode 3 in his tuts so when showing the viewers what exactly should be done to complete certain steps, it is quite difficult to follow along. Here's what I've found that isn't parallel, some of which I am figuring out as I go along, but some is still ambiguous and would be great to be clarified on the site:

1. Resources is supposed to be the same as 4's 'Supporting Files' folder, however doesn't contain the ViewController files I'm looking for that he demonstrates on. (How do I get to the View display?)
2. There's no 'tools' top menu bar option
3. Under this I should be able to find the option item 'Library' which contains 'Attributes' (Where are all of these components located?) - (Actually as I'm going along I'm finding some of these, but for the sake of the site's Q&A style I'll pose the question regardless.)
4. "Build and Run" button on home toolbar is the same as the "Run" button in 4?
5. I clicked the Run button and it built, but I have a big white box rectangle after I was told to put the "Bacon" label on the View Controller (which I ended up finding) - what's up with that?
6. When trying to add an icon to the plist file, the option to do so on the chart is not featured - where is it?
7. Bucky chooses a View Based Application setting when creating a new project. This is not an option in Xcode 4. What is its closest relative?

Answer (score 0):

1. What Bucky shows is actually *not* under the Supporting Files folder, just under the project folder. It will not have the ".xib" ending, but rather a ".storyboard" ending.
2. True. Sorry.
3. The Library you are looking for is in the bottom right hand corner of the window. It is one of the tabs that is currently displaying the "File Template Library". Two tabs down is the object library you're looking for.
4. Yes.
5. Likely, you were creating display components under the iPhone storyboard, and the option bar just a couple buttons right of the Run button will give you the option to display the iPhone simulator. It is possibly set to the iPad display at the moment.
6. You must create the property. Click on one of the properties and a (+) sign will display when the item is highlighted. Click it and a new property value will come up to be defined and type in "Icon File." Ergo, you are ready to follow further into the video tut.
7. Although I am not certain I believe it is known as the "Single View Application" option. It seems to me that they have the same properties.